# OGM: Multi <meta> Tags outside <head>

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We want to send "User downloaded e-book XYZ" to timeline. We have a file "books.php" in this file are 5 other includes (book1.php, book2.php, ...).

When i load book1.php directly its correct: "I downloaded e-book 1". But when i load books.php there is this Error:

> Body Meta:    You have `<meta>` tags ouside of your `<head>`. This is either because your  was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

What can i do, to have more "meta og:title and url"-Tags then one in the first ?

In my dream its like this:

> meta property="og:title[1]"      content="Book1" /
>   meta property="og:title[2]"      content="Book2" /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as you describe it.

Each OG object is made up of a single URL which represents a single object. When Facebook does an HTTP GET on each of your URLs - it will read the OG tags in the HEAD of the HTML returned.

So when Facebook GETs book1.php, in the head of the HTML returned should be the OG markup for Book 1.

When Facebook GETs book2.php, the metadata should be for Book 2 and so on.

OG markup cannot be in the body of the HTML - and you cannot have markup representing multiple objects in a single HTML document.